# Visual Studio How to put the groupbox caption above its contents

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a groupbox in a that contains several other controls. But let's say one of the content controls overlaps the caption / title of the groupbox. It will obscure the title.

How do I make the caption be "more important" than its contents, i.e. it appears on top of them in case of an overlap?

Bringing To Front doesn't do the trick as presumably it applies to the groupbox as a whole (including its contents)

Comment: Why can't you move the child control in such a case? Perhaps use a `TableLayoutPanel` or a `FlowLayoutPanel` in the GroupBox to help ensure layout. Short of a custom user-control for this edge-case, I feel you're working against the framework.